# International student to intern in General Motors Canada

Tags: working-visas, canada, internship, tunisian-citizens

I am Tunisian, residing/going to school in Tunisia. I have landed an opportunity to intern in General Motors Canada as part of my required study curriculum. 
I understand that I need a work permit to intern in Canada. Is a letter from GM sufficient for me to apply for a work permit?

Comment: Hi there, have you spoke to General Motors' recruitment team about this? Usually they should be used to, and be able to help with immigration queries.

Comment: No I haven't. Actually my supervisor will be doing a first bringing an intern overseas and he is concerned it might be too much trouble and investment that the HR people won't do it. I am just looking for information to help my supervisor help me. He thinks if he just asks them to handle everything for me they'll think I am not worth the trouble.